# PHPunit and Mockery: method not found

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I'm having a problem using PHPunit and Mockery. For some reason, PHPunit says that the method `onFoo`, I defined in Mockery, does not exist.

```php
public function testReturnsTheCorrectValueWithClass()
{
    $listener = \Mockery::mock('FooListener');
    $listener->shouldReceive('onFoo')
             ->once()
             ->andReturn('foo');

    $this->eventManager->attach('foo.class', array($listener, 'onFoo'));

    $this->assertTrue($this->eventManager->dispatch('foo.class') === 'foo');
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Does `onFoo` exist in `FooListener`?

Comment: Thanks for your response Zerk! Actually, FooListener is just a class, that has one method, onFoo, and that method returns "foo". Does the class "FooListener" really need to exist? I taught that Mockery mocks that class? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm sure both original class/interface and the target method should exist (not exactly sure about the method though - I have never tried to mock not real classes, since it makes no sense)

Comment: So I need to make a class with that method? But why would I still use Mockery then? Thanks.

Comment: mockery (and any other mock library) provides you an ability to set up an instance of the known class with some known behaviour so that you could inject it as a dependency to a tested object. The more general reason - is to isolate tested class from its dependencies.

Comment: Hmm, but I tried this: http://pastebin.com/srNknmZK, and that just works. That class doesn't exist.

Comment: And it did work? If so - what's the difference with your current code? PS: it's still weird anyway - my code works with real, not imaginary classes :-S

Comment: Yes, the test just passed. I will just post my full code: http://pastebin.com/RtZ54a4D Only the "ReturnsTheCorrectValueWithClass()" test doesn't pass. Thanks

Comment: @zerkms Mockery can handle known classes (mocks) and unknown classes (stubs). From [their guide](https://github.com/padraic/mockery#quick-reference): *"Creates a mock object named foo. In this case, foo is a name (not necessarily a class name) used as a simple identifier when raising exceptions. This creates a mock object of type \Mockery\Mock and is the loosest form of mock possible."*

Comment: @Raoul Van den Berge: "doesn't pass" isn't an explanation. What is the technical difference between tests?

Comment: Well, I'm testing one with closures and one with a listener class. The listener class is the one that gets called by Mockery. Thats the difference, I guess? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem! It had nothing to do with my test code, but with the way my EventManager gets the mock object. I created a new instance of the mock object instead of just using the existing one.

Thanks everyone for the help though!

Comment: "It had nothing to do with my test code" --- that was obvious. If the similar code works with one test, and doesn't in another - then the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: True! Another lesson learned today :) My debugging skills need to get better tough. :)